# Simple CouchDB Fetch and Display records in Common LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am taking my first steps in Common Lisp 
and thanks to clouchdb 
http://common-lisp.net/project/clouchdb/#examples

I managed to fetch some simple data from couchdb

```
      (invoke-view "hulk" "hulk" )
 ((:|total_rows| . 2) (:|offset| . 0) (:|rows| ((:|id| . "gjc") (:|key| . "hulk") (:|value|                             
 (:|_id| . "gjc2321o3io13") (:|_rev| . "3-b6433781c65460f2c9b1f1a153953171")
  (:NAME . "Dr Bruce Banner") (:|kind| . "users") (:|username| . "hulk") (:|title| . "gamma r adia
 tions: what to do ?"))) ((:|id| . "irnmn239223") (:|key| . "ironman") (:|value| (:|_id| . "irnmn2     39223") 

  (:|_  rev| . "5-2b6cf739d24b1208fe8eca70e37ffdc9") (:|name| . "tony stark") (:|title| . 
(:|name| . "tony stark") (:|title| . "why iphone 5 sucks - but i own one \"") (:|kind| . "users") (:|username| . "ironman") (:|text| .  "welcome to post number one ......")))))
```

7 >

I am using SEXML to display the HTML records so my HTML displaying template looks like this

```
 ;;static here 
 (<:h2 "((LISP RETRO BLOG))")
 (<:h3 "(( ***** RETRO BUT STILL COOL *****))")
 (<:p "( (MADE IN LISP ))")
 (<:p "READY.")
 (<:img :src "/img/prompt.gif" :alt "cursor"))
 ;;this is a variable
 (<:p "universal time: " mytime)
```

Now would I create a simple loop through the above mentioned results (e.g. usernames are ironman and hulk) to display something like

```
  (<:p "Welcome!" username)
```

Sorry for posting so much code for what might be in the end a very simple loop. I did read and try examples ( http://psg.com/~dlamkins/sl/chapter05.html) and other resources but I am probably missing something very basic and would appreciate your help. Note that couchdb documents might have different fields so it is not exactly the same as looping through some records where you have a schema. This might be relevant e.g. if a document is a blog post it might or might not include tags so I might want to show / create a page with all the data available in a document (excluding the _id perhaps).

If something is not clear just comment and I will be happy to edit the question.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This looks like a fake question. The Lisp data isn't even a valid s-expression.

Comment: there is no fake data. The first set was fetched using (invoke-view "hulk" "hulk" ) in clouchdb. This is what a couchdb returns using that lisp library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will much better understand the output data, if you reformat it to be more readable. Like this:

```
((:|total_rows| . 2) (:|offset| . 0)
 (:|rows|
   ((:|id| . "gjc") (:|key| . "hulk")
    (:|value|
      (:|_id| . "gjc2321o3io13")
      (:|_rev| . "3-b6433781c65460f2c9b1f1a153953171")
      (:NAME . "Dr Bruce Banner")
      (:|kind| . "users")
      (:|username| . "hulk")
      (:|title| . "gamma radiations: what to do ?")))
   ((:|id| . "irnmn239223") (:|key| . "ironman")
    (:|value|
      (:|_id| . "irnmn2     39223") 
      (:|_  rev| . "5-2b6cf739d24b1208fe8eca70e37ffdc9")
      (:|name| . "tony stark")
      (:|title| .

      ;; here you repeat name and title, so the previous and next lines are erroneous

      (:|name| . "tony stark")
      (:|title| . "why iphone 5 sucks - but i own one \"")
      (:|kind| . "users")
      (:|username| . "ironman")
      (:|text| .  "welcome to post number one ......")))))
```

So, what you got from CouhcDB via clouchdb is a specially structured list, which is called **alist** in Lisp parlance. There's a set of functions for working with alists, the most important of which is `ASSOC`.

The result tells you, that you have 2 rows, each one holding the data as another alist. To iterate over them you can use the following function:

```
(defun maprows (fn data)
  (mapcar fn (cdr (assoc :|rows| data))))
```

Now you have to pass into `MAPROWS` a function `FN` of one argument. For example, if you want to just print the values in a sensible manner, you can pass the following function.

```
(defun print-row (record)
  (dolist (pair (cdr (assoc :|value| record)))
    (format t "~A: ~A~%" (car pair) (cdr pair)))
  (terpri))
```

Let's see how it works:

```
CL-USER> (maprows 'print-row
                  '((:|total_rows| . 2) (:|offset| . 0)
                    (:|rows|
                     ((:|id| . "gjc") (:|key| . "hulk")
                      (:|value|
                        (:|_id| . "gjc2321o3io13")
                        (:|_rev| . "3-b6433781c65460f2c9b1f1a153953171")
                        (:NAME . "Dr Bruce Banner")
                        (:|kind| . "users")
                        (:|username| . "hulk")
                        (:|title| . "gamma radiations: what to do ?")))
                     ((:|id| . "irnmn239223") (:|key| . "ironman")
                      (:|value|
                        (:|_id| . "irnmn2     39223") 
                        (:|_rev| . "5-2b6cf739d24b1208fe8eca70e37ffdc9")
                        (:|name| . "tony stark")
                        (:|title| . "why iphone 5 sucks - but i own one \"")
                        (:|kind| . "users")
                        (:|username| . "ironman")
                        (:|text| .  "welcome to post number one ......"))))))
_id: gjc2321o3io13
_rev: 3-b6433781c65460f2c9b1f1a153953171
NAME: Dr Bruce Banner
kind: users
username: hulk
title: gamma radiations: what to do ?

_id: irnmn2     39223
_rev: 5-2b6cf739d24b1208fe8eca70e37ffdc9
name: tony stark
title: why iphone 5 sucks - but i own one "
kind: users
username: ironman
text: welcome to post number one ......

(NIL NIL)
```

As you see, `MAPROWS` also collects the results of application of `FN`, as does the underlying `MAPCAR`.

Comment: (maprows 'print-row '((:|total_rows| . 4) (:|offset| . 0) (:|rows| ((:|id| . "flower-photo-with-lytro") (:|key| . "flower-photo-with-lytro") (:|value| . "3558566236")) ((:|id| . "hello-world-in-common-lisp-and-restas") (:|key| . "hello-world-in-common-lisp-and-restas") (:|value| . "3558567019")) ((:|id| . "the-circus-is-nice") (:|key| . "the-circus-is-nice") (:|value|)) ((:|id| . "yet-another-lisp-test") (:|key| . "yet-another-lisp-test") (:|value|)))))
> Error: value "3558566236" is not of the expected type LIST.
> While executing: PRINT-ROW, in process Listener(32).

Comment: any idea why the above doesn't work? the only difference is that it includes now the date in unix format or did the view change the overall structure ?

Comment: Yes, the structure has indeed changed. Now `:|value|` field holds an atom instead of list. It can be fixed very easily with this change to `print-row`: `(let ((val (cdr (assoc :|value| record)))) (if (atom val) (print val) (dolist (pair val) ...) ...`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little bit different approach, although, I'm not entirely content with it. Perhaps someone will correct me / suggest a better way, but this overall strategy is known as object mapping. I.e. when you retrieve data from a table in database, you would build an object that is more comfortable in the language you program your application logic.

Now, ironically, CouchDB was supposed to surpass this stage - because it encodes objects into JSON format, it would be "native" to JavaScript, where it is commonly used. But, the format you received it in CL is not comfortable to work with / it's not a good native representation of objects. Now, since you cannot use CL in the client browser application, I don't really see a point in the combination you have... I mean, you don't win anything on the server side (most likely, you will loose performance-wise, but since this is your personal blog, this is not likely to be an issue).

So, below is an attempt at some naive object mapping:

```
(defclass db-object () ())

(defun slot-list-from-query (query)
  (mapcar
   #'(lambda (pair)
       (let ((name (string-upcase (symbol-name (car pair)))))
         (list (intern name)
               :accessor
               (intern (concatenate 'string name "-OF"))
               :initarg (intern name "KEYWORD")))) (eval query)))

(defmacro table-to-class (name describe-table-query)
  `(let ((db-class (defclass ,name (db-object)
                     ,(slot-list-from-query describe-table-query))))
     (defmethod initialize-instance :after ((object ,name) &key raw-data)
                (mapcar
                 #'(lambda (pair)
                     (setf (slot-value object
                                       (find-symbol
                                        (string-upcase
                                         (symbol-name (car pair)))))
                           (cdr pair))) raw-data))
     db-class))

(defparameter *raw-data*
  '((:|total_rows| . 2) (:|offset| . 0)
    (:|rows|
     ((:|id| . "gjc") (:|key| . "hulk")
      (:|value|
        (:|_id| . "gjc2321o3io13")
        (:|_rev| . "3-b6433781c65460f2c9b1f1a153953171")
        (:|name| . "Dr Bruce Banner")
        (:|kind| . "users")
        (:|username| . "hulk")
        (:|title| . "gamma radiations: what to do ?")))
     ((:|id| . "irnmn239223") (:|key| . "ironman")
      (:|value|
        (:|_id| . "irnmn2     39223") 
        (:|_rev| . "5-2b6cf739d24b1208fe8eca70e37ffdc9")
        (:|name| . "tony stark")
        (:|title| . "why iphone 5 sucks - but i own one \"")
        (:|kind| . "users")
        (:|username| . "ironman")
        (:|text| .  "welcome to post number one ......"))))))

(table-to-class example-mapping (car (cdaddr *raw-data*)))
(id-of (make-instance 'example-mapping :id "foo")) ; foo
(id-of (make-instance 'example-mapping :raw-data (car (cdaddr *raw-data*)))) ; gjc
```

I took liberties to "fix" your data a little bit so that it looks consistent. Also, normally you would have your tables description prior to running your code, so the entire hassle of declaring classes at runtime would be reduced to some mechanic operation which you would do prior to deployment, and there wouldn't be any need for `eval` in this macro. I've posted it like this in order to preserve the information you have and to give it a look as if it was received after the code was deployed.

If you wanted to use it, you'd remove `eval` and do something like:

```
(table-to-class example-mapping ((name-1 . value-1) (name-2 . value-2) ...))
```

Comment: +1; I've used this approach in PHP; it's a nice abstraction IMO. cl-sql uses this technique as well: "CLSQL provides an Object Oriented Data Definition Language, which provides a mapping from SQL tables to CLOS objects. " Here: http://clsql.b9.com/manual/csql-rel.html